# Can a bachelor of software engineering study masters of electrical engineering?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, engineering, changing-fields, electrical-engineering

I'm currently in the process of applying to college for undergraduate degree in software engineering. I really love everything about electronics from hardware to software. I find it difficult to choose between electrical engineering or software engineering till I decided to take software engineering then continue my education for master in electrical engineering. Though, I'm not looking to offer myself more job opportunities, I literally want to know every single bit about hardware and software. My question:

Is it possible to study software engineering and then masters in electrical engineering?

Comment: In Canada at least this is fairly common, for someone to graduate with CS degree or engineering degree, then switch their specialization once they get to masters level. Although it usually depends on how popular the subject is, as the less popular ones are usually easier to get positions with.

Comment: @user25345 Please post your answers in form of answers posts not comments.

Comment: Just to add a data point. I got a BS in CS and did MS in EE in USA.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the program you apply for your masters degree. Some universities and educational systems accept changing fields for masters degrees and some others not. Some programs may require the applicant to study some more courses from the bachelors syllabus to help them be more prepared for their masters program.

I think you would better ask the program you want to apply to, to see whether they accept and consider applications with different bachelors degree or not.

Comment: This is essentially what happened with me. I've crossed from BS in Computer Science to MS in Electrical Engineering. Since I had some "holes" in my background, I had to take some undergrad courses on top of my master level courses.

Answer (score 0):

I know this it is a late response but maybe this will help others. If I was in that situation I would get an undergraduate degree in Computer Engineering. Computer Engineers have to take software and hardware courses. At many universities, they can specialize in either by taking senior electives. However, it really depends on what you want to do. Computer Engineers will not usually take courses in Electromagnetics or Device Science. Those courses are specifically for Electrical Engineers.